# How can I catch opening of the link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML page with multiple links. Is there any ability to catch the event of opening the link? Users can just click on link or can open it on the new window or tab by right click.

Links refers to external resources and I can not control of its content.

Comment: Link onclick event may help you.

Comment: <A PING> was designed for this and works even on right-click...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few client-side options that I can think of, none of which ideal:

- You could replace the link's `href` with a `javascript:` url that ran any code you wanted, and then navigated to the correct URL (`location.href = "http://example.com"`). This is nasty though, since it breaks if the user does right click -> new tab or has JavaScript disabled.
- You can add an event listener to the click event of the `<a>`. But this would not get triggered on right-click -> open, or a user tabbing over and pressing enter.
- You can use an `onunload` event handler on the document itself, but this won't tell you where the user is going, and wouldn't work if the user opened a new tab.

If you just want to track where your users are navigating to, then a server-side solution is the only foolproof way. You would have to send users to your own server, which would in turn send an HTTP 302 code to redirect the browser to the correct URL. This would, of course, require more infrastructure than you may want.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try to describe my task.  I have a page with multiple links which I have generated on the server.  The user want open some of this link on new tabs (it is important - he don't want to loose current page state).  The links user have opened must be hidden.  If I understand correctly I can not use first and second options as it doesn't works with 'new tab'.  And I can not use third option because the user open links in the new tab and keep current page opened. May be there is other ways to solve my task? Hmmm... may be I can use CSS and hide all visited links on my page....

Comment: Yes, you could do `a:visited { display: none; }`. This would persist over multiple sessions, which you may or may not want. Also, I'm not sure how different browsers' privacy modes might affect it since checking for `:visited` is a (slightly awkward) way to discover a user's history.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use javascript to do something like...

```
 $('a').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).alert("do something");
 });
```

Comment: Does it works for right click and open link for context menu ?

Comment: Thanks for the mark down...who ever that was. You could you .change and i believe that would work for right click.

Comment: @jibsales, jQuery is not a problem.

Comment: Could you post some more code, can do a proper solution then.

Comment: @jibsales, jquery is tagged.

Comment: @Samsquanch Thats because I tagged it

Comment: This code (http://pastebin.com/45WQ8rM4) doesn't work for right click -> open in new tab in the Chrome

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i< links.length; i++) {
  links[i].onmousedown = function(e) {
    console.log(this.href, this)
    if ((e.which && e.which == 3) || (e.button && e.button == 2)) { // not sure about IE
      alert('right click');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect it alert if I will right-click on the link, but not open it in the new page or tab.  Is it right ?

Comment: @demas, Yes, but it will prevent to open default context menu and you can create custom context menu.